# How is this hierarchy supposed to function?

Tags: swift, generics, polymorphism

I'm making a Framework for a school project, and I've decided to use Generics as a baseline for each UIView. I tried adding these 'Entities' to a Generic Dictionary that will take a type 'Entity'. The class I am trying to add to this list is named 'EntityPlay', and is a subclass of 'Entity'. I attempt to add this class to the Dictionary, however I get a compile error dictating that 'EntityPlay' and 'Entity' are incompatible.

I mapped out the Hierarchy for the Entity, and came to the conclusion that there isn't anything wrong with saying that an 'Entity' is actually just a 'Entity'.

```swift
public class View {
    private var map : [Entity<UIView>]
    private func addEntity<T : Entity<UIView>>(_ entity : T) -> Void {
        self.map.append(entity)
    }
}

public class Entity<T : UIView> {
    some code
}

public class SomeClass {
    public func someFunc() -> Void {
        view.addEntity(EntityPlay())
    }
}
public class EntityPlay : Entity<UIImageView> {
    some code
}
```

I expected that this code should work completely fine given the above logic, but it resulted in a compile error dictating that 'EntityPlay' had nothing to do with 'Entity'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sidebar note: if you are aiming to call `addEntity` from outside of its class, you cannot declare it as a `private`.*

**The Problem:**

The reason of the error when calling `view.addEntity(EntityPlay())` is:

`addEntity` method takes an argument of type `Entity<UIView>` which is *not* the type of `EntityPlay`; In other words, `Entity<UIView>` ≠ `Entity<UIImageView>` even if you think of it as "but `UIImageView` is basically `UIView`!", it is not the case when dealing with generics.

**Solution:**

You might need to create an abstraction layer for declaring a collection that contains *heterogeneous* types. As a good practice you could create a new protocol thus you declare `map` array of the protocol type. Example:

```
protocol EntityProtocol {
    func doSomething()
}

public class View {
    private var map : [EntityProtocol] = []
    func addEntity<T : EntityProtocol>(_ entity : T) -> Void {
        self.map.append(entity)
    }
}
```

At this point, you need to make `Entity` to conforms to `EntityProtocol`; Therefore, since `EntityPlay` inherited from `Entity`, it would also implicitly conforms to `EntityProtocol`:

```
public class Entity<T : UIView>: EntityProtocol {
    func doSomething() {
        print("Entity!!")
    }
}

public class EntityPlay : Entity<UIImageView> {
    override func doSomething() {
        print("EntityPlay!!!")
    }
}
```

**Output:**

For checking the output, let's call `addEntity` twice, passing `Entity` and `EntityPlay` instances to it:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public func someFunc() -> Void {
        let view = View()
        // Entity
        let entityView = Entity()
        view.addEntity(entityView)

        // EntityPlay
        let entityPlay = EntityPlay()
        view.addEntity(entityPlay)

        // let's assume that `map` is public:
        for e in view.map {
            e.doSomething()
        }
    }
}

let test = SomeClass()
test.someFunc()
// Entity!!
//EntityPlay!!!
```

Comment: Yes, I do recognize that there were some syntactical errors in the post above (of which none were present in my project). I appreciate your response; I assumed that Swift acted somewhat like Java when it came to polymorphism and such, and I know now that they shouldn't be treated as such. Again, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have a better time building your hierarchy of classes if you were to just subclass UIView to make your Entity class. Is there a specific reason you need to use generics?

My guess for what is happening is that you've defined a dictionary that can only take an Entity - when you attempt to add the EntityPlay class to it, it is an imageView, which causes this issue. If your dictionary was explicitly defined to be able to take [Any:Any] you could probably get around this - but you'd have to unwrap every result that came out of it as they would all be optionals. Needless to say, this would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

`EntityPlay` and `Entity` are not compatible types. When you set a generic's type, you can imagine that it's a completely new class definition.